# Sharing App components

Tags: android, service, process, share

I have an application A, it contains activities, services and receivers.
I need to modify my code so that any future application (ex: B and C) can launch services located in app A, and perhaps access its preferences files.

However, I want to restrict access to app A's components to applications developed by me only.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to implement a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) and add permissions you like for which App has access to what.

Comment: ContentProviders doesn't not solve my problem, I need to share Components (Activities, Services) and not databases

Comment: If you are talking about using the same classes of your code in different Apps, then you can create a common library and import it as an external JAR for other Apps.

Comment: no no man, you're not getting my point, I dont want to share classes nor jars, I want app B to launch app A's service for example, and access its private files ex: preferences, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution:

using the same android:sharedUserId on both applications will do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with permissions for components.

> An application can also protect its own components (activities,
>   services, broadcast receivers, and content providers) with
>   permissions. It can employ any of the permissions defined by Android
>   (listed in android.Manifest.permission) or declared by other
>   applications. Or it can define its own. A new permission is declared
>   with the  element.

See [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) for examples.

Comment: maybe that's the closest solution to my problem so far, however is it possible to grant these permissions to applications with same signature? in other words, I don't want third part apps to be granted this permission...

Comment: Do you have info who called your component?